# stylesheet based on case sensitive url

Tags: css, orchardcms

I am out of options at this moment, since i do not have any idea why i have this behaviour. Working with Orchard CMS 1.4 and a custom superfish stylesheet. The behaviour is somehow differend based on how the site is accessed. Our customer has made a theme and it is as demo on a simple website at the following url.

https://assicuro.unit4demo.nl/acceptatie-1.0.1

If u browse to this url u see the menu with a image from https://assicuro.unit4demo.nl/acceptatie-1.0.1/themes/assicuro/content/images/nav-bg.jpg

This is the background of the menu when it is not hovered.

After browsing to the url, click the Home button and see the url being changed into

https://assicuro.unit4demo.nl/Acceptatie-1.0.1   (notice the capital A)

Is there anybody with some idea's how it is possible that the background image is not being showed? All tips are welcome!

Comment: The capital A is there because it's hard coded into the theme that way. Why not just change it to a small a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the background-image is being overwritten by another CSS style:

```
//This is from "/Acceptatie-1.0.1/ (Line 51)"

#menu-24.sf-menu li.selected, #menu-24.sf-menu li.current {
    background: #F1F1F1 !important;
}
```

This could also be based on the Layout files, if you are using URL Alternatives for the Layouts of different pages.

*(If I remember correctly, Orchard CMS has issues dealing with URLs that contain certain characters, such as hyphens, which might be another issue to consider.)*

Comment: In acceptatie-1.0.1 (without the capital A) it is also being overwritten by the other css style? since it is #menu-24 it does not matter does it? About URL Alternatives, i will look at that.

Comment: You may want to consider using the Shape Tracing Module - it is great for realizing which Layouts and Shapes your different Content and Widgets are inheriting from.

Comment: i had a file called Content-HomePage.cshtml in the theme, where some Meta was not being excluded. Sadly enough it was not the problem. Thru it only goes wrong on the Home page.

Comment: It was inside in the admin panel for the Szmyd advanced menu. Several menu's are being. A differend menu at the HomePage layer. Thanks Rionmonster for pointing me into the right direction.

Comment: Glad it helped you out - definitely consider using Shape Tracing in the future. It can be a lifesaver.

Comment: The Shape Tracing module has a bug somehow, giving a warning with a javascript. But that will be another question ;)

Comment: Yes - it can often conflict when using other JS libraries.